# streamingresponsebody AsyncConfiguration hanging if clients cancels the request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have developed an Spring Boot application with below components. "/download" api is hanging if clients cancels the request, until all threads are completed. Also "/download" api will not accept  new request until all the tasks of cancelled thread completed, responding with 500 internalservererror without any details
[image]

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.task.AsyncTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncConfigurer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ConcurrentTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.async.CallableProcessingInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.async.TimeoutCallableProcessingInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.AsyncSupportConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncConfiguration.class);

    /** http request timeout value, 1 hour */
    int timeOutValue = 3600000;

    @Override
    @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
    public AsyncTaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor() {
        /** Create async thread pool */
        logger.info("Creating Async Task Executor");
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new AsyncRejectedExecutionHandler());
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        logger.error("Async Export blob UncaughtException");
        return new PdngExceptionAsync();
    }

    /** Configure async support for Spring MVC. */
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurerConfigurer(AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor,
            CallableProcessingInterceptor callableProcessingInterceptor) {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
                configurer.setDefaultTimeout(timeOutValue).setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
                configurer.registerCallableInterceptors(callableProcessingInterceptor);
                WebMvcConfigurer.super.configureAsyncSupport(configurer);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public CallableProcessingInterceptor callableProcessingInterceptor() {
        return new TimeoutCallableProcessingInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public <T> Object handleTimeout(NativeWebRequest request, Callable<T> task) throws Exception {
                /** Throw exception if request time exceeds the timeOutValue */
                logger.error("Export blob request timeout");
                return super.handleTimeout(request, task);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

```
@GetMapping(path = "/download")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getBlobFile(
            @RequestHeader(value = TOKEN, required = false) String token, @RequestParam("id") String id)
            throws PdngException, JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException, IOException {
        
        /** Stream chunks by downloading chunks in batches */
        StreamingResponseBody responseBody = response -> downloadService.streamingResponseBodyBiConsumer.accept(response,
                chunkids);
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok().header("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + id)
                .header("Content-type", "application/octet-stream").body(responseBody);
    }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <reactor-netty>1.1.0</reactor-netty>
        <reactor-core>3.5.0</reactor-core>
        <log4j>[2.19.0,)</log4j>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- exclude junit 4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- junit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j}</version>
            <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <!-- Please don't remove/degrade the version, possible for compatibility 
                issues -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j}</version>
            <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <!-- Please don't remove/degrade the version, possible for compatibility 
                issues -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20220924</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.34.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
            <version>12.20.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-cosmos</artifactId>
            <version>4.38.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>${reactor-core}</version>
            <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <!-- Please don't remove/degrade the version, possible for compatibility 
                issues -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
            <version>${reactor-netty}</version>
            <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <!-- Please don't remove/degrade the version, possible for compatibility 
                issues -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```
[2022-12-02T14:13:21.021Z] [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [218] [DEBUG] [] [] Securing GET /download?id=12345
[2022-12-02T14:13:21.021Z] [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [104] [DEBUG] [] [] Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
[2022-12-02T14:13:21.021Z] [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [100] [DEBUG] [] [] Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[2022-12-02T14:13:21.021Z] [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [333] [DEBUG] [] [] Secured GET /download?id=12345
[2022-12-02T14:13:21.021Z] [org.springframework.core.log.LogFormatUtils] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [119] [DEBUG] [] [] GET "/download?id=12345", parameters={masked}
[2022-12-02T14:13:21.021Z] [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [522] [DEBUG] [] [] Mapped to com.projectcontroller.DownloadController#getBlobFile(String, String)
[2022-12-02T14:13:21.021Z] [com.projectcontroller.DownloadController] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [111] [INFO ] [] [] getBlobFile(download/blob API) method called.
[2022-12-02T14:13:21.021Z] [com.projectbusiness.TokenValidation] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [140] [INFO ] [] [] validateAccessControl called.
[2022-12-02T14:13:21.021Z] [com.projectbusiness.TokenValidation] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [83] [INFO ] [] [] validateToken called.
[2022-12-02T14:13:21.021Z] [com.projectbusiness.TokenValidation] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [90] [DEBUG] [] [] Expiration: Fri Dec 02 16:10:58 GMT 2022
[2022-12-02T14:13:21.021Z] [com.projectbusiness.TokenValidation] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [126] [INFO ] [Random UUID] [ClientApi] validateToken completed.
[2022-12-02T14:13:21.021Z] [com.projectdao.ClientApiLogDAO] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [45] [INFO ] [Random UUID] [ClientApi] saveClientApiLog called.
[2022-12-02T14:13:21.021Z] [com.projectdao.ClientApiLogDAO] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [64] [INFO ] [Random UUID] [ClientApi] saveClientApiLog finished
[2022-12-02T14:13:21.021Z] [com.projectbusiness.TokenValidation] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [331] [INFO ] [Random UUID] [ClientApi] verifyAuthorization ended
[2022-12-02T14:13:21.021Z] [com.projectbusiness.TokenValidation] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [160] [INFO ] [Random UUID] [ClientApi] validateAccessControl completed.
[2022-12-02T14:13:21.021Z] [com.projectservice.impl.DownloadServiceImpl] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [63] [INFO ] [Random UUID] [ClientApi] chunkids called.
[2022-12-02T14:13:21.021Z] [com.projectservice.impl.DownloadServiceImpl] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [238] [INFO ] [Random UUID] [ClientApi] getStorageFile called
[2022-12-02T14:13:21.021Z] [com.projectservice.impl.DownloadServiceImpl] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [239] [DEBUG] [Random UUID] [ClientApi] getStorageFile called: fileName: 12345.json ,containerName: chunk-id
[2022-12-02T14:13:22.022Z] [com.projectservice.impl.DownloadServiceImpl] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [118] [INFO ] [Random UUID] [ClientApi] chunkids completed.
[2022-12-02T14:13:22.022Z] [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [486] [DEBUG] [] [] Started async request
[2022-12-02T14:13:22.022Z] [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [1107] [DEBUG] [] [] Exiting but response remains open for further handling
[2022-12-02T14:13:22.022Z] [com.projectservice.impl.DownloadServiceImpl] [taskExecutor-1] [127] [INFO ] [] [] streamingResponseBodyBiConsumer called.
[2022-12-02T14:13:22.022Z] [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [360] [DEBUG] [] [] Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
[2022-12-02T14:13:22.022Z] [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [120] [DEBUG] [] [] Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
[2022-12-02T14:13:24.024Z] [com.projectservice.impl.DownloadServiceImpl] [taskExecutor-1] [358] [INFO ] [] [] getBlobDataMapFromChunkMap ended.
[2022-12-02T14:13:27.027Z] [com.projectservice.impl.DownloadServiceImpl] [taskExecutor-1] [358] [INFO ] [] [] getBlobDataMapFromChunkMap ended.
[2022-12-02T14:13:27.027Z] [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] [319] [DEBUG] [] [] Async request error for /download/blob: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
[2022-12-02T14:13:27.027Z] [com.projectservice.impl.DownloadServiceImpl] [taskExecutor-1] [185] [ERROR] [] [] Chunk download failed for chunk, blob id:  ABCDE : {}
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:353)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.appendByteArray(OutputBuffer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:388)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
        at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:638)
        at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:638)
        at com.projectservice.impl.DownloadServiceImpl.lambda$new$0(DownloadServiceImpl.java:179)
        at com.projectcontroller.DownloadController.lambda$getBlobFile$0(DownloadController.java:133)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler$StreamingResponseBodyTask.call(StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler.java:111)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler$StreamingResponseBodyTask.call(StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler.java:98)
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.lambda$startCallableProcessing$4(WebAsyncManager.java:337)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:79)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:50)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:466)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:135)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1424)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:768)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:593)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:537)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:547)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:112)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:194)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:340)
        ... 17 common frames omitted
[2022-12-02T14:13:27.027Z] [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] [399] [DEBUG] [] [] Async error, dispatch to /download/blob
[2022-12-02T14:13:27.027Z] [com.projectutils.Utils] [taskExecutor-1] [431] [INFO ] [] [] getExceptionCode called : java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
```

Comment: And the question is? The server doesn't know anything about an aborted connection and just sends, that is the way HTTP works.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, but if we try to submit new request for downloads receiving 500 internal server error until streaming of failed request.

Comment: Correct, because the server doesn't know until it flushes/commits the response, which can only be done in the end.

Comment: Spring boot (Java) Rest API is Stateless and also multi thread, so if one request (call request A) is failed it should not impact other request (call request B). Why Request B is receiving 500 error until Request A flushes/Commits

Comment: Because all threads are busy... It has nothing to do with state, but the fact that resources are in use. So if there is nothing left to take the resouce it will return a 500 because it eventually times out.

Answer (score 0):

As per below link it is high recommended to use a TaskExecutor, I added singleton TaskExecutor at application level.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/StreamingResponseBody.html

Also I used ExecutorService & CountDownLatch inside the Download api. When User cancels the download, capture that exception and then shutdownnow & cancel all the futures

```
    public BiConsumer<OutputStream, JSONArray> streamingResponseBodyBiConsumer = (responseStream,
                array) -> {
            List<Future<Boolean>> futures = null;
            int limit = 100;
            int noOfIterations = array.length() / limit;
            int noOfConcurrentJobs = noOfIterations + 1;
            ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(noOfConcurrentJobs);
            List<Callable<Boolean>> callables = new ArrayList<Callable<Boolean>>();
            
            for (int i = 0; i <= (noOfIterations); i++) {
                int endIndex = 0;
                int startIndex = i * limit;
    
                if (i < array.length() / limit) {
                    endIndex = (i + 1) * limit;
                } else {
                    endIndex = (array.length());
                }
                Model model = new Model(startIndex, endIndex);
                callables.add(() ->/**stream data*/ streamData(array, responseStream, model,countDownLatch));
            }
            
            try {
                futures = executorService.invokeAll(callables);
                executorService.shutdown();
                countDownLatch.await();
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                logger.error("Interrupted : {}", exception);
                throw exception;
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (Objects.nonNull(executorService)) {
                        if (!executorService.isTerminated()) {
                            executorService.shutdownNow();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    logger.error("Failed to shutdown executor service: {}", exception);
                }
                try {
                    if (Objects.nonNull(futures)) {
                        futures.stream().filter(future -> {
                            try {
                                return !future.isDone() || future.get();
                            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                                return !future.isDone();
                            }
                        }).map(future -> future.cancel(true));
                    }
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    logger.error("Failed to cancel future jobs: {}", exception);
                }
            }
            if (responseStream != null) {
                try {
                    responseStream.close();
                } catch (IOException exception) {
                    logger.error("Streaming failed : {}", exception);
                }
            }
    
        };

public class Model {
    
    private Integer startIndex;
    private Integer endIndex;
    
    public Model(Integer startIndex,Integer endIndex) {
        this.endIndex=endIndex;
        this.startIndex=startIndex;
    }
    /**
     * @return the startIndex
     */
    public Integer getStartIndex() {
        return startIndex;
    }
    /**
     * @return the endIndex
     */
    public Integer getEndIndex() {
        return endIndex;
    }
}
```